# Serialization of set

Tags: java, json, serialization

I am trying to write my own `Set` serializer, `HashSet` specifically. This because the default output of such a set holding enum elements looks like this:

```
modifier: {
    amount: 1
    criteriaSet: {
        class: java.util.HashSet //<--- bothers me
        items: [
            NONE                
            ADD
            MULTIPLY
        ]
    }
}
```

So I thought I write my own serializer. this is what the write method looks like.

```
@Override
public void write(Json json, HashSet object, Class knownType) {
    json.writeObjectStart();
    for (Object o : object)
    {
        if (o instanceof Modifier.Criteria)
            json.writeValue("name", ((Modifier.Criteria) o).name());
    }
    json.writeObjectEnd();
}
```

This works but it requires me to name the field and thus the output is like this:

```
modifier: {
    amount: 1
    criteriaSet: {
        name: NONE
        name: ADD
        name: MULTIPLY
    }
}
```

This works but since the default `Set` serializer does not write the field names (name:) I want that too. Just writing the enum name yields an error `json.writeValue(((Modifier.Criteria) o).name());` : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Name must be set.`

I have tried this for `EnumSet` first because `EnumSet` works more efficient with sets of `Enum` but I ran into problems too. I am looking for a clean solution to store `Enum` values into a `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean that you want it to be an json array (`[..]`) instead of json object (`{...}`). In that case use `writeArrayStart()` and `writeArrayEnd()`. See also: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-and-writing-JSON

Comment: Great that works. But now I have issues de-serializing it. Funny thing is, my overridden read method does not even get called. Any idea why this is?

Comment: I think that is because json is seeing a arraylist but the field is a HashSet. But shouldnt the read method run first and return the proper type? `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Set field com.buckriderstudio.towercrawler.Creature.Modifier.criteriaSet to java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: Which read method? If you have another question then perhaps ask another question including the relevant details.

Comment: Yeah I should. Anyway, was talking about the read method implemented by the serializer interface. You need a write and a read method.